# Lodash Filter with Multiple Functions

Tags: javascript, filter, lodash, code-readability

Trying to figure out the cleanest way to do the following:

I'm filtering some results twice, and I'm using Lodash filter to do so. Currently, my code looks like:

```
resultsOne = _.filter(results, functionOne);
resultsTwo = _.filter(resultsOne, functionTwo);
```

I realize I could combine functionOne and functionTwo, but I like them broken apart for readability. Is there a best practice for filtering with two functions, either using Lodash or plain ol' Javascript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Lodash to chain these two filters together, with the [`_(…)` constructor](https://lodash.com/docs/#lodash), or more correctly, *wrapper*:

```
let filtered = _(results).filter(functionOne).filter(functionTwo).value()
```

The `_(…)` wrapper wraps a value, the array in this case, and allows it to be chained with other functions such as `_.filter`. The array would be passed as the array to be filtered, and the function as the predicate. The `value()` call at the end unwraps the value.

Of course, with ES5, this operation becomes extremely trivial, and Lodash can create unnecessary clutter:

```
let filtered = results.filter(functionOne).filter(functionTwo);
```

This reduces library dependence with builtin methods and is easily chainable without wrappers.

And you could even use vanilla JavaScript to combine them:

```
let filtered = results.filter(result => functionOne(result) && functionTwo(result))
```

This checks against both functions. This is similar to `_.overEvery` suggested by Ori Diori which composes an arbitrary number of predicates into a single filter predicate.

Answer (score 8):

**Using lodash**

You can create a filtering function using [`_.overEvery()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#overEvery), and use it in the filter:

```
var ff = _.overEvery([functionOne, functionTwo]);

var filteredResults = results.filter(ff)
```

**Vanilla JS**

Create an array of filter functions, and apply them to a value using [Array#every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
var filters = [functionOne, functionTwo];

filterdResults = results.filter(function(item) {
  return filters.every(function(ff) {
    return ff(item);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this perhaps?

```
results.filter(functionOne).filter(functionTwo);|
```